# Image Hover Effect one by one in jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to show image overlay effect my code is that

```
jQuery("div.footer_recent_post ul li a img").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).mouseover(function(){
        jQuery('div.image-overlay').slideDown(500);
    });
});

<div class="image-overlay" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class"footer_recent_post">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>
          <img class="th wp-post-image" width="80" height="80" src="image-path">
        </a>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

I have 4 images and when I mouser hover on any image image-overlay div show on all images,
I want to only one by one, how can I do??

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to get the closest matching `.footer_recent_post` ancestor div when traverse up the DOM tree.

After that, you can apply **[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)** to get the immediate previous sibling with class `image-overlay`:

```
jQuery("div.footer_recent_post ul li a img").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).mouseover(function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.footer_recent_post').prev().slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

Also note that you're missing `=` to assign the class name in your HTML markup. It should be `class="footer_recent_post"` instead of `class"footer_recent_post"`

---

Currently, you're only handle the case when you mouse over the image, you should slide up the content when mouse out as well using `.mouseout()`:

```
jQuery("div.footer_recent_post ul li a img").each(function () {
    jQuery(this).mouseover(function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('.footer_recent_post').prev().slideDown(500);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('.footer_recent_post').prev().slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

You can shorten above code using `.hover()` and `.slideToggle()` as well:

```
jQuery("div.footer_recent_post ul li a img").each(function () {
    jQuery(this).hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('.footer_recent_post').prev().slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/daqX6/)**